# Text Format Toolbar

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formatting, text-editor

I am looking for how to implement a toolbar similar to the one used here when you add a new question, this toolbar should format the text entered in my text box and allow me to make it Bold, Italic, choose size and fond and highlights, colors as well...
One important thing, I want one that is both supported on firefox and IE, discountasp.net offers one which is only supported by IE.

PS: I am coding my website in asp.net 3.5, vb.net, MS SQL 2005 Express, and all is done with MS VWD 2008 express.

And I may add that I am not a programming guru, I just make things work, so keep it simple folks ;)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should give a try to the http://nicedit.com/ it will turn any text area or text box to a nice editor just like the one used in SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the SO Editor [here](http://github.com/cky/wmd/tree/master).